# How to remove view permission from everything?

Tags: permissions

I want to give my friend access to a single folder on my server.

I created a new user for him, created a new group for him, and `chgrp -R`'d the folder for him so that he would have access.

I just tried SSHing in as him, and he can see everything on my server. He can see all the directories, `cat`, and download files. The only thing he can't seem to do is modify or create files.

How can I remove access for him from everything except his home folder and this special folder for which he is in the group of?

---

Here's what I've done, I ran `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added this to the bottom:

```
Match group GROUP
    ChrootDirectory /srv/WEBSITE
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

And then ran `service ssh restart`.

Now I can't log in as my friend using WinSCP.

Comment: This might help somewhat: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245804/give-access-to-a-specific-user-to-a-specific-folder-within-a-group-terminal

Comment: Also this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179333/how-can-i-disable-access-to-the-file-system-for-a-specific-user-or-group

Comment: This one tells you how to make only your group (or only yourself) able to access your home folder. It can be adapted.

Comment: What I would do is build a proper `chroot` environment for this user. See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory

Comment: @noleti "All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group." -- That's a pretty ridiculous restriction. At a minimum, I need `www-data` to be able to read/write to that directory.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Those links only describe how to remove permissions for a specific folder. I want to remove permissions from *every other* dir/file in the entire file system. Is `chmod -R o-rwx /` (i.e. on the root folder) safe to do?

Comment: @Mark `www-data` can have write right to the directory content, but not to the parent directories. The point is to prevent another user from redirecting the path to another folder on the filesystem via `ln -s` or similar.

Comment: I also strongly advise against changing rights of all other folder with the `chmod` commands you mention. That is a sure way to mess up your system beyond recovery.

Comment: @noleti That's what I was thinking.... good thing I didn't run it.

Comment: You can't block access to the whole filesystem, since, like one of those links explains, there are executables and programs that need to be run.

Comment: @Zacharee1 By "other"? What's running as "other"?

Comment: When did I say other?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I was talking about running `chmod -R o-rwx /` which removes read/write/execute permissions for "other users". Would that not remove access for my friend?

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yes... that's precisely what I want. And then I asked if it was safe to do. And then you both said no, it's not safe. Which is it? Will my server explode if I do that or not?

Comment: Sorry. Tired. Don't block access to root. You'll be fine, but that group won't even be able to login, since Unity, drivers and built in startup apps won't be able to load.

Comment: @noleti - chroot is somewhat depreciated (it still has uses), use LXC =)

Answer (score 1):

You are not very clear on the things your friend is supposed to do in the folder. As you state that `www-data` should have write rights as well, I assume this is a web data directory. For this, `sFTP` or `scp` would be my tools of choice for your friend. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory) answer explains how to set up both in a `chroot` environment. If your friend actually has to log in via ssh, you may need to copy some binaries for him to use, or use `ln -s` to link `/usr` into the chroot environment.

Comment: `scp` access will be sufficient for him, although shell access wouldn't hurt for future reference. I've updated my question with what I've tried... now I can't log in with his account at all.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure how you would log in with scp - you just use it to copy files. If you want him to log into your server using SSH, you will have to copy binaries for him to execute. I have never done that myself, so I can't help with that part.